# Can I move my Minecraft account from an iPad to a laptop running Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I purchased and downloaded Minecraft 1.14 for my son some time ago - this was on his iPad - but he now wants to play on his laptop, which is running Windows 10.  I have downloaded Minecraft: Java Edition for Windows onto the laptop and followed the instructions on the launcher. However, when I started the program and signed in with his account details, I couldn't access the game without having to pay again.

I have read somewhere that this may be because his account was purchased via the App Store on the iPad and this isn't transferred across to Windows, which seems strange, since I can still log into his account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the [Minecraft App Store page](https://apps.apple.com/app/minecraft/id479516143) it states:

> **This app is available only on the App Store for iPhone and iPad.**

This version of Minecraft is indeed not the Java Edition, but the Pocket Edition. You are able to log in to the Mojang account because it isn't tied to a specific game.

Comment: Ah!  thanks for the answer.  I didn't check at the time of purchasing as he only wanted it for the iPad.

Comment: Would you know if the account he has will be shared across the platforms if I purchase the Java edition?

Comment: Yes, it should be: "Mojang accounts were later introduced as a single account to use across all Mojang games" (see [here](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360034636772-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Account-Types)).

Answer (score 0):

No,it will not go across screens, I tried it once too, but it has to be purchased separately i think because on pocket addition it is purchased from icloud account (usually) and for computers it's xbox account.

Comment: for the microsoft acounts yes it will be shared